# JavaFX - How do i create a button for each element on my array?

Tags: arrays, button, javafx

So i want to **create a list of button for each element on my array**.
If i have 10 objects on the array, i want to create 10 buttons right away.
Thank you

Comment: Please show us some code. What have tried so far? What does your array contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create buttons where? You need a container to add them to (IIRC something that extends Parent).

```
String[] sa = new String[10];
for (String s : sa) {
  Button b = new Button(s);
  vBox.getChildren().add(b);
}
```

If you use SceneBuilder and FXML to design your views (leaving out anything dynamic like this), you can assign containers like a VBox an ID, which will automatically add a reference with an @FXML annotation when you generate a controller class. That will give you a reference to a container to add the buttons to.